# Python Unittest: make sure patched class is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, ddt

I have the following code

```
@ddt
@patch('mymodule.myclass', MagicMock)
class MyTest(): 
    @data([val1, val2])
    @unpack 
    def test_run(self, val1, val2):
         ClassA().run(val1, val2)
```

How Do I assert some methods inside `mymodule.myclass` are called?

Comment: If I patch the class/method at test_run() function level, I can assert it easily, but now the patch is at the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you patch it at the class level you get a reference to the mock as an argument in your test methods, for instance:

```
@ddt
@patch('mymodule.myclass', MagicMock)
class MyTest(): 
    @data([val1, val2])
    @unpack 
    def test_run(self, val1, val2, my_class_mock):
         # use my_class_mock
```

You can use this mock for many purposes but in this case you'd still need to patch your class inside the test method to make your assertions.